# Data manipulation of long format with unbalanced observations

Tags: r, dataset, mixed-models

I am organizing my data for using mixed models.

The data are unbalanced in regards to nr of observations.

It looks something like this:

```
Id <- c("A","A","A","A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D","D","D","D","D","D")
v1 <- c(5,5,5,5,8,8,8,15,15,4,4,4,4,4,4)
v2 <- c(3,3,3,3,5,5,5,10,10,8,8,8,8,8,8)

my_data <- data.frame(Id, v1, v2)

head(my_data, n = 20)
```

v1 and v2 can be seen as static predictors as they have the same value over ID. The data are unbalanced in regard to number of observations.

Question A = How do I  calculate the mean of the static predictor v1 (the mean of one observation of v1 per ID).

Question B = How do I use something like "cut numbers" to organize v1 into a new static predictor with 3 levels ("Low", "Median", "High") in a new column in the dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question A:

```
mean(tapply(v1, Id, mean))
```

Question B: use the `cut()` function.